# am i on the right track? Cashier Program C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and was wondering if i was on the right track? I'm kind of confused about this but  was hoping for possibly some helpful hints on things i am missing/ have wrong....i know its not completely finished i still need to do the breakdown of the dollars,quarters....etc

Question: A cash register uses an automated coin machine to help make change. We assume that a clerk is handed money to pay for purchases. For change, the clerk returns to the customer any paper money and directs the coin machine to distribute any changes less then $1. In this exercise, you are to simulate the action of the clerk and the machine.

At the cash register, we need access to the purchase price and the payment. The change, which is the difference between the payment and the purchase prices, is a real number. The whole part represents the change in dollars and the fractional part is the change in cents that is returned in quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. For instance, with a payment of $10 to cover purchases of $3.08, the required change is $6.92. The clerk hand out $6 and the coin machine distributes 3 quarters, 1 dime, 1 nickel, and 2 pennies for the 92 cents.

92 = 3(25) + 1(10) + 1(5) + 2

Use real-number objects that identify the purchase price (price), the amount of payment (payment), and the change (change). The main program computes the amount of change (coinChange) and partitions it into dollars (dollars), quarters (quarters), dimes (dimes), nickels (nickels), and pennies (pennies).

You must declare constants for quarters (quarters), dimes (dimes), nickels (nickels), and pennies (pennies). You must use compound operators in the calculations. You must use setreal(w,p) and setw(n) for the output.

What I have done so far:

```
// Me
// A BRIEF PROGRAM DESCRIPTION FOR CHAPTER 2, HOMEWORK 4

// COMMENT THE PREPROCESSOR 
#include <iostream.h>

// COMMENT THE PREPROCESSOR STATEMENT
#include "textlib.h"

int main( )
{

// COMMENT THE CONSTANTS
const int QUARTER_AMOUNT = 25;
const int DIME_AMOUNT = 10;

// COMMENT THE OBJECTS
double price;
double payment;
double change;

int numofDollars;
int numofQuarters;
int numofDimes;
int numofNickles;
int numofPennies;

int coinChange;


cout << "Enter the purchase total: ";
cin >> price;
cout << "Enter the payment: $";
cin >> payment;


// COMMENT THE CALCULATION
change =  payment - price;
numofDollars = int(change);
coinChange = (int((change / numofDollars) * 100));
numofQuarters = coinChange / 25;
coinChange = coinChange / (numofQuarters * 25);
numofDimes = coinChange / 10;
numofNickles = coinChange / 5;
numofPennies = coinChange / 1;

// OUTPUT THE INFORMATION

return 0;
}
```

Comment: So uh... what's your question?

Comment: you can just paste code into your question, then higlight it all and hit the code button

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What makes StackOverflow somewhat unique is that it is a *question-and-answer* site. It isn't a discussion site, a code-review site, nor a homework repository. On StackOverflow, you ask a question and people respond. Do you have a specific question (at least, more specific than "am I on the right track?")? If so, please edit your post to ask it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are on the right track. Your general structure is sound. These sorts of homework assignments almost always have a structure like this:

```
int main () {
  // read in the data
  ...

  // Do the math
  ...

  // Write out the data
  ...
}
```

You do have some math errors. Try stepping through the code with a pencil and paper, pretending that **you** are the computer. Also, try stepping through the code with your debugger, examining the variables after each line. Compare what actually happened to what you expected.

Comment: I would highly recommend trying to use the debugger if at all possible.  Knowing how to use breakpoints, watches, and other debugging tools are essential when programs get more complex.

Comment: Agreed. I changed the language of the post to reflect your advice.

Comment: So i got my program to work....sort of.....when i go to run it....i type in 3.08 as the cost 10.00 as the payment and it gives me the correct 6.92 total...but when it breaks it up into dollars quarters nickles, dimes and pennies it seems to be missing 1 dime 1 nickle and 1 penny.....any suggestions??

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code line-by-line. What should the variables hold at each step? What **do** they hold? What is the very first thing that is unexpected? Why did it happen?